# The number of particles in PDG, and what the data includes

Tags: particle-physics, data

I checked [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2005/mcdata/mass_width_2004.mc) for computer-readable PDG particle data, and count about 174 unique particle IDs there, which seems like an awfully small number of particles to be "every particle type there is in the universe", especially with imagining what might be happening at the CERN experiments.

Looking [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/listings/contents_listings.html) at "PDG particle listings", it lists:

- Gauge & Higgs Bosons (gamma, g, W, Z, ...)
- Leptons (e, mu, tau, neutrinos, heavy leptons ...)
- Quarks (u, d, s, c, b, t, ...)
- Mesons (pi, K, D, B, psi, Upsilon, ...)
- Baryons (p, n, Lambda_b, Xi, ...)

[Clicking](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/listings/rpp2019-list-photon.pdf) into one of them shows "γ (photon)", with no "PDG ID". [Another](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/listings/rpp2019-list-c-quark.pdf), same thing.

I'm wondering if one could explain what is included in those PDFs that is not included in the first linked text file, and how the IDs from the text file relate to the PDFs.

In the end I would like to find a list of all the particles and all their properties, but after having looked several times through PDG I haven't been able to clearly identify it.

Comment: Do you understand that most of these are *composite* particles?

Comment: No I don't understand much at all yet from these PDFs, sorry. I want to though.

Comment: There are only a small number of fundamental (non-composite) particles. Depending on how you count them, there are as few as 17.

Comment: @G.Smith sweet, wondering if you can show me where I can find those 17, data for them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Comment: And in (pre-brane) string theory, there is just *one* kind of “thing”: string! And I think it has only one property, tension. How’s *that* for Reductionism?

Comment: [Uh oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle): "Though extremely successful, the Standard Model is limited to the microcosm by its omission of gravitation and has some parameters arbitrarily added but unexplained"

Comment: Nobody loves the Standard Model. But it is still impressive given that we didn’t even understand how an atom worked until about 100 years ago.